# How to assign a domain name to a device on a local network?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, ip-address, domain-name

I have a product that allows users to control the operation of an equipment over a wifi network. In this local network there is a webserver (apache), which I would like to access via a custom domain name rather than its ip address. How can I achieve this?

Just to put things into perspective, I have a tplink router where you can put a domain name "tplinkwifi.net" in the address bar of a browser which will redirect you to the router's ip address, in my case 192.168.0.1. I would like to replicate this for my webserver on the local network.

Comment: Its not your fault, but your question is really too generic to be anaswered here, as there are lots of possible variants of lots of possible solutions depending on your hardware, software and situation - from editing hosts files, to modifying dnsmasq to setting up authoriative DNS servers to WINS resolution.

Answer (score 3):

You have 3 options:

**Option 1**: Setup a local DNS server

**Option 2**: Set your router to act as a DNS server, if supported

**Option 3**: Edit the "hosts" file on your operating system (`%WINDIR%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` on Windows; `/etc/hosts` on *nix) and add the value:

```
IP_address Domain
```

Example:

```
10.0.0.55 apache.io
```

Comment: Thanks for reply guys, I thought about the hosts solution, but won't I have to then update the hosts file in all devices attached to this network? The users may use their android or ios devices to control the equipment. I think Ill try the DNS server option -  would you be kind enough to point me to some software/hardware that you may have used in the past?

Comment: well, `bind` has been the most common *nix DNS server for many years. but we don't do software/hardware recommendations here, so you will have to shop around. I'd pick your OS, and go from there.